# DNS servers not correctly set in VPN

Tags: 12.04, dns, openvpn, resolv.conf

I have to use an OpenVPN network to work from home, and I occasionally have problems getting DNS to resolve. The problem comes and goes, and I can't reproduce it reliably.

I took the OpenVPN config that my employer provided and fed it into the "Import" part of the VPN tab in the Network Manager settings (after installing `network-manager-openvpn`, of course).

The DNS servers automatically provided by the VPN did not appear to work reliably. so I went to the "IPv4 settings" tab of the VPN settings and changed it to "Automatic (VPN) addresses only" and put the search domain and servers in by hand. However, if I go to "Connection Information", I still see my system dns resolvers listed, and I cannot resolve anything that isn't on public dns.